# On the definition of the Van Vleck-Morette determinant

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, definition, differentiation

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\sigma$ the world function. The Van-Vleck-Morette determinant $D$ is defined by
$$D(x,x')=\det(-\sigma_{;\mu\nu{}'})$$
Regarding the semi-colon: In chapter $4.1$ of [K] it is claimed that it "denotes differentiation with
respect to the Levi-Civita connection", but in other references it is simply interpreted as partial differentiation$^1$:
$$\sigma_{;\mu\nu{}'}=\frac{\partial^2\sigma}{\partial x^\mu\partial(x')^\nu}$$
In any case, it is not clear to me why $D$ is supposedly coordinate-independent (even if we restrict ourselves to normal coordinates), as it is claimed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/135653/281518).

---

$^1$

From chapter $4.1$ of [K]:

> [image]

From page $38$ of [B]:

> [image]

From [C]:

> [image]

**References**

[K] Klaus Kirsten, [Spectral Functions in Mathematics and Physics](https://doi.org/10.1201/9781420035469)

[B] Barvinsky and Vilkovisky, [The generalized Schwinger-Dewitt technique in gauge theories and quantum gravity](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(85)90148-6)

[C] Steven Christensen, [Vacuum expectation value of the stress tensor in an arbitrary curved background: The covariant point-separation method](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.14.2490)

Comment: The semicolon is a somewhat common notation for the *covariant* derivative w.r.t. the LC connection. Other sources should not interpret this as "partial differentiation" - I assume they write what you wrote for $\sigma_{;\mu\nu'}$ **inside** of $\mathrm{det}$ and then there should be factors of $\sqrt{g}$ in front of the determinant corresponding to the difference between the partial and the covariant derivative. Is this correct? If not, please name at least one of these "other references" explicitly.

Comment: @ACuriousMind "The semicolon is a somewhat common notation for the covariant derivative w.r.t. the LC connection." - Could you please explain what that means? AFAIK the LC connection acts on **vector fields** and $\sigma$ is scalar-valued...

Comment: Most texts extend the covariant derivative to act on arbitrary *tensor* fields, not just vector fields, with the covariant derivative of *scalars* coinciding with their ordinary derivative (cf. e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Formal_definition)). When you have an expression $f_{;\mu\nu}$, then the *first* derivative will be just a partial derivative but since the second one then acts on the vector field $f_{;\mu}$, the difference matters.

Comment: @ACuriousMind … *but since the second one then acts on the vector field $f_{;μ}$, the difference matters* No. $σ$ is a biscalar, i.e. it depends on two points $(x,x')$, the first differentiation is for the first point argument, while the second diff is for the second point argument, so $σ_{;μ}$ is not a covector at $x'$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I agree that I can apply the Levi-Civita-connection to the differential of $\sigma$, but the expression $(\nabla\mathrm{d}\sigma)_{\mu\nu{}'}$ does not make sense (since we are considering two tangent vectors in different points), does it?

Comment: @A.V.S. I agree that this is the common definition, but then there is no way that the determinant is coordinate-independent (because the two indices refer to two different points), is there?

Comment: @ACuriousMind "If not, please name at least one of these "other references" explicitly." - I have added two references :)

Comment: @Filippo: I think that there are two different  but related entities that are called vV determinant (in different sources), they differ by a factor $\sqrt{-g(x)}\sqrt{-g(x')}$, and your [B] reference denotes them as $\mathscr{D}$ and $\mathit{\Delta}$. The $\mathit{\Delta}$ would be a biscalar, coordinate independent, while  $\mathscr{D}$ would transform as density under coordinate change.

Comment: Here is a useful reference [Poisson et al.](https://doi.org/10.12942/lrr-2004-6), section 7.

Comment: @A.V.S. Thank you for the reference! Now I see that it is not a coincidence that I got correct results by replacing $\Delta$ with $g^{-1/2}$ (where $g$ is the absolute value of the determinant of the metric in normal coordinates): They are equal according to equation $(107)$. For now I am content with that.